# Server for end production dAPP?

Tags: go-ethereum, react, server-side, hosting, releases

I'm talking for end-production purposes and I'm interested what server specification and which hosting services dAPP developers use.

Considering my scenario, I made a decentralized application in React however I still need server to read Blockchain instruction on each request of the user.

I haven't released my project yet, it doesn't contain any forms of authentication, it's 100% Blockchain based (fetching & writing instruction through MetaMask) and I was thinking to go by this dedicated server:

```
2TB Storage (RAID-10)
Unlimited Bandwidth
8 CPU Cores, 16 Threads (Intel based : E5-2630v4 at 2.4GHz per core).
16GB DDR4 RAM
```

I hope it can sustain a good amount of users.
I investigated different hosting services for the front end of dAPPs such as [TMDHosting](https://www.tmdhosting.com/)

What type of hosting services do you use for dAPPs?

Is a Blockchain request made by the user 'heavy' on the server side?

Comment: If you wrote and then bundle your application correctly you will end up with 1 html file and a bundle.js which you can server from a very low end server + CDN. You don't need a "backend" server, if you're just using the blockchain. Just default to using the MetaMask provided web3 connection that talks to infura / their own node the way they want it. Your app does not need to care / know.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So if my website reads data from the blockchain and puts it on each user's screen, does that not require server performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole purpose of DApps is that you don't need to setup a back-end for them, since the Blockchain acts as a common back-end shared across all DApps. Most of the time, a simple static HTML/JS/CSS front-end application will be sufficient for DApp projects. For my DApp projects, I make heavy use of AWS S3 to store the front-end single page applications from which users can connect to the Blockchain using their MetaMask wallet.

This [gist](https://gist.github.com/bradwestfall/b5b0e450015dbc9b4e56e5f398df48ff) explains in much details how you can leverage AWS services to build a performant SPA hosting.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Makes much more sense for me right now. I will lower my service requirements which will make me save some finance :)